# Lighweight DMS for personal use

Tags: linux, open-source, document-management

I need a small, lightweight DMS for personal use, which is available on Linux.

**Requirements:**

- runs on Linux
- manages PDF
- stores documents in the file system¹ in an easily recognizable structure²
- offers a GUI (WebUI is fine, native Linux GUI as well)
- not too many dependencies (e.g. no KDE libs as I don't use KDE)
- tags, manual descriptions
- find documents by tags, name, date, description

**Strongly preferred:**

- available via standard repositories (Debian/Ubungu/Mint) or at least easy to install
- OCR capabilities (for full-text search), or at least offering full text search for documents having text (for PDF, e.g. integrated via pdfsandwich; for LibreOffice, extracted from the document)

**Nice to have:**

- maintains other formats (images, ODF (LibreOffice/OpenOffice) documents)
- integrated document viewer capable to deal with supported formats
- scan folders for (new) documents (so I can drop them in the right place and the DMS indexes them). A special "drop folder" is OK, but even better if I can place the documents where they belong. The folder(s) don't need to be monitored; manually triggering the index process is totally fine.
- custom fields
- grouping of connected documents (think of "book series" having multiple volumes). This could e.g. also be achieved by attaching/merging multiple documents onto/into a single record.

Using a database backend for metadata is fine (it it does, preferably SQLite or MySQL).

**Not needed:**

- multi-user, approvals etc. (as pointed out above: personal use only)
- Windows compatibility
- "reference systems". I just need to manage my own documents. References between those are fine – but I'm not collecting external references.
- encrypted storage (if that's needed, I can encrypt the file system)

**Definitely unwanted:**

- cloud-based (unless self-hosted) – so no Evernote, please.

---

I know we have quite a few DMS questions, but none of them completely meets my requirements. Most of them are asking for collaborative features, but I only want a light-weight variant for personal use. Coming close (and how they miss):

- [Free document management system with file system integration](/q/49945/185): .NET, MSSQLServer, other MS related, eMail updates
- [PDF organizer with virtual hierarchy, fast viewer, highlighting, search](/q/47573/185): rather looks for a reference system
- [Free software document management](/q/43455/185): automated processing, email, mirrors
- [Document manager for paperless office](/q/736/185): Windows
- [Simple open source document scan/tag/catalog more lightweight than Alfresco](/q/21328/185): very close; but no FOSS, no OCR

I've also seen [paperless](https://github.com/danielquinn/paperless) which basically fits the above, but seems pretty complex to install. [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/) is already mentioned in the footnotes; but in addition to that it's rather for reference management.

---

¹ <sub>should the software die, I still can find and access the documents</sub>
² <sub>e.g. Zotero fails this one, using cryptic directory names</sub>

Comment: Have you also looked at http://nemakiware.com/ - I came across it in the past. Not used it yet but planned to when required. You can search for it on stackexchange as it is under a few answers.

Comment: Thanks, but that sounds too big as well: I don't need multi-account, team collaboration etc – and I don't like having to register for the download. I meanwhile settled with a directory tree of PDFSandwhiched PDFs and `pdfgrep` for search. Not elegant, but does the job :)

Answer (score 1):

Due to the lack of alternatives, I've settled for a very minimalist approach meanwhile. All ingredients are available from the standard repositories on Ubuntu/Mint, though for more up-to-date versions, at least for one part I instead used the Debian package offered at the project's website:

**[PDFSandwich](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsandwich/)** is a wrapper around some tools like [unpaper](https://www.flameeyes.eu/projects/unpaper) (to optimize pages for better OCR results), [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr) (for OCR'ing the PDFs) and some helpers like Ghostscript and ImageMagick. You feed it a PDF, and it spits out another one which combines the original one with its OCR results:

```
pdfsandwich -lang eng sample.pdf
```

will result in `sample_ocr.pdf`, which is a sandwich of the two.

Now, I organize the documents in an appropriate directory structure. And when I still don't know what PDF has the contents I'm after, I switch to the root directory and use

```
pdfgrep -r -i foobar
```

Which spits out a list of each line from all the documents containing "foobar", prefixed by the `path/to/document.pdf`.

No elegant GUI, but it does its job. Let's see how it meets my original criteria:

- **runs on Linux:** Yes.
- **manages PDF:** Indeed.
- **stores documents in the file system¹ in an easily recognizable structure²:** My job, but: Yes.
- **offers a GUI (WebUI is fine, native Linux GUI as well):** No, just a CLI
- **not too many dependencies (e.g. no KDE libs as I don't use KDE):** Definitely.
- **tags, manual descriptions:** can be realised in the file names. Again, not elegant (e.g. no "global tag rename"), but possible.
- *find documents by tags, name, date, description:* Not exactly – but sufficient for my use. "By content" is done via `pdfgrep`, "by name" can be done via `| grep <name>`, "by date" via other CLI tools (like `awk`to isolate the file name, then `ls -l` or `stat` to get the date and filtering that way – a bit heavy, though :)

The "nice-to-haves" are only vaguely met (sure I can put all other file types into the structure – but then search would be difficult as `pdfgrep` only deals with PDF, etc. There's no "global index" to search). So I'm still open for alternatives – but for now, this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using [paperless.node](https://github.com/uriagassi/paperless.node) I've created:

- runs on Linux, Windows or Mac
- manages PDF, images, emails
- stores documents in the file system their original form in a flat directory
- offers a WebUI
- tags, manual descriptions
- find documents by tags, name, description
- easy to install
- integrated document viewer
- has a drop folder

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Great. Please what are main differences with something like https://github.com/paperless-ngx/paperless-ngx apart from fact that paperless.node retains original directory? Thanks.

Comment: @ZZ - to be perfectly honest - I was not aware of the paperless-ng project, so I do not have a full comparison. My solution is more lightweight, and has less track record (part of being a project that one person worked on it for a couple of months, vs a project multiple people worked on for multiple years...).
I hope it has all the needed requirements, but I would appreciate feedback :)

Comment: Thanks, that looks good! But I stopped reading in the middle of the first install step. I might be opinionated there, but I don't want to use NodeJS. But it indeed seems more comfortable – especially as it includes the DMS part. Will certainly be what a lot of people like!